# how to include file system object properties in excel vba dynamic array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, file, recursion

I am trying to work out how to use filesystemobject to include date created, date modified, size, path, file/folder names of files and folders into an excel vba dynamic array so that it automatically expands or contracts to the list of files/folders.

In addition, I am trying to make a list of excluded folder paths so that when I click search, only those folder paths and its files are excluded from the result list, but other folders and its files are shown. Is it possible to make a list of folder paths which will exclude deeper nested folder subfolders?

For example, In this folder C:\test with spaces\ (see image) [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udn6O.png) I want to exclude the file in C:\test with spaces\subfolder 1\2ndlevelsubfolder1\ including "2ndlevelsubfolder1", but I want all other folders paths to be displayed. How can I do this with vba?

Finally, I also want to make this list recursive, so that every time I add/remove the excluded list of folder paths, new entries will be added right after the previous list. I have these functions made in different excel workbooks but the only problem is incorporating them together into one code. I am showing you my code from 2 workbooks:

1. This code is for recursive listing:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SomeSub()
    Call GetFiles("\\?\[INSERT PARENT FOLDER PATH HERE]") 'attach "\\?\" at the beginning for long folder path names! ex..'GetFiles("\\?\INSERT..."
    'can also list multiple "Call GetFiles("\\?\[insert new folder path here]")" to list multiple folder paths all at once
End Sub
Sub GetFiles(ByVal path As String)
Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim folder As Object
Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(path)

Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim file As Object

For Each SubFolder In folder.Subfolders
    GetFiles (SubFolder.path)
Next SubFolder

Range("A1") = "parent folder"
'Range("A1").Offset(0, 1) = "FILE/FOLDER PATH"
Range("A1").Offset(0, 3) = "FILE or FOLDER"
Range("A1").Offset(0, 4) = "DATE CREATED"
Range("A1").Offset(0, 5) = "DATE MODIFIED"
Range("A1").Offset(0, 6) = "SIZE"
Range("A1").Offset(0, 7) = "TYPE"
    
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Replace(folder, "\\?\", "")
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Replace(folder, "\\?\", "")
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = folder.Name
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3) = "FOLDER"
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) = folder.datecreated
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5) = folder.DateLastModified

For Each SubFolder In folder.Subfolders
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Replace(subfolder.path, "\\?\", "")
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Replace(folder, "\\?\", "")
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = subfolder.Name
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3) = "FOLDER"
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) = subfolder.datecreated
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5) = subfolder.DateLastModified
Next SubFolder

For Each file In folder.Files
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Replace(file.path, "\\?\", "")
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Replace(folder, "\\?\", "")
    'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = file.Name
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3) = "FILE"
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) = file.datecreated
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5) = file.DateLastModified
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6) = file.Size
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7) = file.Type
Next file

With Range("E:F")
.NumberFormat = "dddd mmmm dd, yyyy H:mm:ss AM/PM" 'long file date and time
End With

Set FSO = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set SubFolder = Nothing
Set file = Nothing

End Sub
```

2. This is the excluded folder name list code in cell A3 only the names are inserted at cell A3 seperated by commas with no spaces after the comma. I want folder paths at any subfolder level to be excluded, not just names at the 1st level

```
Option Explicit
'http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=158478
Dim iRow As Long

Sub ListFiles()
    Dim lRow As Long
    iRow = 11
    lRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow >= iRow Then
      Range("B" & iRow & ":E" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Clear
    End If
    Call ListMyFiles(Range("A1"), Range("A2"), Range("A3")) 'Cell A1 is the parent directory, A2 is include subfolders as false or true _
                                                                cell A3 is the exclude folder names within the parent directory _
                                                                which only works in the 1st level not deeper nested levels
    Application.GoTo Range("B3"), True
End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath As String, IncludeSubfolders As String, _
  Optional excludedSubfolders As String = " ")
    Dim myObject As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim mySource As Scripting.folder, myFile As Variant
    Dim myfolder As Variant
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim mySubFolder As Scripting.folder, v As Variant
    Dim asf() As String, sf As String
    
    asf() = Split(Replace(excludedSubfolders, ", ", ","), ",")
    
    Set myObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If Right(mySourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then mySourcePath = mySourcePath + "\"
    Set mySource = myObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
    On Error Resume Next
      
    For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
        iCol = 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = mySubFolder.Path
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = mySubFolder.Name
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next mySubFolder
    
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            If excludedSubfolders = " " Then
              Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)
              Else
              sf = Trim(Right(mySubFolder.Path, Len(mySubFolder.Path) - Len(mySourcePath)))
              If IndexStrArray(asf(), sf) = -1 Then Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)
            End If
            Next
            End If
End Sub

'val is not case sensitive
Function IndexStrArray(vArray() As String, sVal As String) As Long
  Dim v As Variant, i As Long
  On Error GoTo Minus1
  For i = 0 To UBound(vArray)
    If LCase(vArray(i)) = LCase(sVal) Then
      IndexStrArray = i
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next i
Minus1:
  IndexStrArray = -1
End Function
```

I hope this has shed some light on what I want to achieve. Thank you & hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it'll 100% match your needs.
You should use collections, and recursive sub, like this (not fully tested, it might needs some corrections):

```
' List of complete path of files in folder / subfolders
' Needs to add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference to your file
Sub FolderFilesPath(ByVal pFolder As String, ByRef pColFiles As Collection, _
    Optional ByVal pGetSubFolders As Boolean, Optional ByVal pFilter As Collection)
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oFolder, oSubFolder As Folder
    Dim oFile As File
    
    sFolder = IIf(Right(pFolder, 1) <> "\", pFolder & "\", pFolder)
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
    If Not ExistsInCollection(pFilter, oFolder) Then
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            pColFiles.Add oFile
        Next oFile
        If pGetSubFolders Then
            For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
                FolderFilesPath oSubFolder.Path, pColFiles, pGetSubFolders, 
pFilter
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub

' Vba collection contains
Function ExistsInCollection(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo err
    ExistsInCollection = True
    IsObject (col.Item(key))
    Exit Function
err:
    ExistsInCollection = False
End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub TestMe()
    Dim colFiles As New Collection, sFilePath As Variant
    Dim colExcludedFolders As New Collection
    With colExcludedFolders
        .Add "C:\test with spaces\subfolder 1\"
    End With
    FolderFilesPath ThisWorkbook.Path, colFiles, True, colExcludedFolders
    ' colFiles contains filtered files
    For Each sFilePath In colFiles
        With sFilePath
            Debug.Print .Path & " - " & .Name & " - " & .DateCreated
        End With
    Next sFilePath
End Sub
```

Comment: this code gives me an error "Run-time error '70': Permission denied" and when I click debug it takes me to line "For Each oFile In oFolder.Files"

Comment: actually what i want is the filesystem object properties to be filled in the cells not in debug.print and also I want the subfolders to be listed eith the files not just the files

Answer (score 0):

Now i am getting Run-time error '28': Out of stack space

What is wrong with this code?